# How to Render Echarts Map with Heatmap in React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, echarts

I am trying to use Echarts on my React app, but i can't use the map chart integrated with google maps, like this example:
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-polygon.

On the docs example it uses baidu map, but I want to use with google maps. How to pass the options of the chart to a google maps render like react-google-maps/api?